# sending notification with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notification to users with firebase cloud messaging when they are being sent friend request in my app using the below function which i deployed to my firebase functions

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notifications_id}').onWrite(event => {
 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
 const notifications = event.params.notifications;

 console.log('This User Id is :', user_id);
});
```

but when it trys to send the notification, i get the following error in my functions logs

```js
 sendNotification
 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:8:30)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:758:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: check if the `user_id` is exist in `event.params` by adding line `console.log(event.params)`

Answer (score 1):

you have to add context and get the parameter from there. Try:

```
            ..'use strict'

            const functions = require('firebase-functions');
            const admin = require('firebase-admin');
            admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

            exports.sendNotification = functions.database
              .ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notifications_id}')
              .onWrite((event, context) => {

                   const user_id = context.params.user_id;
                   const notifications = context.params.notifications;

                  console.log('This User Id is :', user_id);
            });
```